# GraphQL support with django-saleor Ecomm platform

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, saleor

I need to know to what degree saleor supports GraphQL? My understanding is that the front end is just django templates, but I see a graphql folder there, so what is it?
I was told by the moderators to take a look into the demo branch. I need to know how different is it compared to the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Saleor is expanding its support for GraphQL as the goal is to rebuild both the dashboard and the storefront as single-page applications powered by React. Currently the API is not complete as it does not yet provide mutations for the checkout process. The demo branch uses GraphQL to filter products in category listings: https://demo.getsaleor.com/products/category/books-1/

Comment: Thank you for your response. So this means you are using django for the bank-end and react in front, am I Right?

Comment: Also, this means the demo branch is more upto date than the master and should check out demo instead?

Comment: Demo has more features but it's not more up to date. Master does not have all the features as it's getting ready to replace them with better versions in the upcoming months.

Comment: Hey Patrys, Just wanted to touch base and see if the saleor is now an SPA? Your online demo still refreshes the page when I browse, so can you give me some updates? Which branch is complete in that sense?Thanks